# smoothing a contour for hand using OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I have this code but my contours for hand are not smooth. How can I fix it?

```
void Hand::analyzeHand(cv::Mat xyzMap)

    {

        cv::Mat normalizedDepthMap;
        cv::Mat channel[3];
        cv::split(xyzMap, channel);
        cv::normalize(channel[2], normalizedDepthMap, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

        // Resize input
        cv::Mat input;
        cv::pyrUp(normalizedDepthMap, input, cv::Size(normalizedDepthMap.cols * 2, normalizedDepthMap.rows * 2));

        cv::pyrUp(input, input, cv::Size(input.cols * 2, input.rows * 2));
        cv::Mat threshold_output;
        std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

        // Find contours
        cv::threshold(input, threshold_output, 100, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
        cv::findContours(threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

        // Find contour polygon
        std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        for (auto i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) 
        {
            cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
        }

        // Find largest contour
        auto contour = Hand::findComplexContour(contours);

        // Find approximated convex hull

        std::vector<cv::Point> hull;
        std::vector<cv::Point> completeHull;
        std::vector<int> indexHull;
        if (contour.size() > 1) 
        {
            cv::convexHull(contour, completeHull, false, true);
            cv::convexHull(contour, indexHull, false, false);
            hull = Hand::clusterConvexHull(completeHull, Hand::CLUSTER_THRESHOLD);
        }

        // Find convexityDefects
        std::vector<cv::Vec4i> defects;
        if (indexHull.size() > 3) 
        {
            cv::convexityDefects(contour, indexHull, defects);
        }

        // Find max and min distances
        double minVal, maxVal;
        cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
        cv::minMaxLoc(channel[2], &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
        // Find center of contour
        auto center = Hand::findCenter(contour);
        centroid_xyz = xyzMap.at<cv::Vec3f>(center.y / 4, center.x / 4);
        centroid_ij = cv::Point2i(center.x, center.y); // SCALING
        // Generate visual
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(input.rows, input.cols, CV_8UC3);
        auto color = cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0);
        // Draw contours
        cv::circle(img, center, 5, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

        for (auto i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::drawContours(img, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
        }

        // Draw hull
        cv::Point index;
        cv::Point index_right;
        cv::Point index_left;
        double farthest = 0;

        if (hull.size() > 1) 
        {
            for (auto i = 0; i < hull.size(); i++)
            {
                auto p1 = hull[i];
                auto p2 = hull[(i + 1) % hull.size()];
                //cv::line(img, p1, p2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
                if (p1.y < centroid_ij.y && Util::euclideanDistance2D(p1, centroid_ij) > farthest)
                {
                    farthest = Util::euclideanDistance2D(p1, centroid_ij);
                    index = p1;
                    index_right = hull[(i + 1) % hull.size()];
                    index_left = hull[(i - 1) % hull.size()];
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw defects (filter)

        std::vector<cv::Point> endpoints;
        std::vector<cv::Point> fingerDefects;
        cv::Point lastStart;
        auto found = -1;
        for (auto i = 0; i < defects.size(); i++) 
        {
            auto defect = defects[i];
            auto start = contour[defect[0]];
            auto end = contour[defect[1]];
            auto farPt = contour[defect[2]];
            // Depth from edge of contour
            // std::cout << "Depth: " << depth << "\tThreshold: " << cv::norm(maxLoc - center) << "\t";
            // Defect conditions: depth is sufficient, inside contour, y value is above center
            auto depth = defect[3];

            // maxLoc largest depth
            // first condition replace with meters distance from the edge
            // second test if inside the hull (no change)
            // above the center (no change)
            if (cv::norm(maxLoc - center) * 15 < depth && cv::pointPolygonTest(hull, farPt, false) > 0 && farPt.y < center.y) 
            {
                auto pt1 = xyzMap.at<cv::Vec3f>(farPt.y / 4, farPt.x / 4);

                if (Util::euclidianDistance3D(pt1, centroid_xyz) > 0.05) 
                {
                    endpoints.push_back(start);
                    endpoints.push_back(end);
                    fingerDefects.push_back(farPt);
                }
            }
        }

        // Cluster fingertip locations

        endpoints = Hand::clusterConvexHull(endpoints, Hand::CLUSTER_THRESHOLD);
        for (auto i = 0; i < endpoints.size(); i++)
        {
            auto endpoint = endpoints[i];
            cv::Point closestDefect;
            auto minDefectDistance = 1 << 29;
            for (auto j = 0; j < fingerDefects.size(); j++)
            {
                if (cv::norm(endpoint - fingerDefects[j]) < minDefectDistance) 
                {
                    minDefectDistance = cv::norm(endpoint - fingerDefects[j]);
                    closestDefect = fingerDefects[j];
                }
            }
            auto endPoint_xyz = Util::averageAroundPoint(xyzMap, cv::Point2i(endpoint.x / 4, endpoint.y / 4), 10);
            auto closestDefect_xyz = Util::averageAroundPoint(xyzMap, cv::Point2i(closestDefect.x / 4, closestDefect.y / 4), 10);
            auto finger_length = Util::euclidianDistance3D(endPoint_xyz, closestDefect_xyz);

            if (finger_length < 0.08 && finger_length > 0.025 && endpoint.y < closestDefect.y) 
            {
                fingers_xyz.push_back(endPoint_xyz);
                fingers_ij.push_back(cv::Point2i(endpoint.x, endpoint.y)); // SCALING

                defects_xyz.push_back(Util::averageAroundPoint(xyzMap, cv::Point2i(closestDefect.x / 4, closestDefect.y / 4), 5));
                defects_ij.push_back(cv::Point2i(closestDefect.x, closestDefect.y)); // SCALING
            }
        }

        if (static_cast<float>(cv::countNonZero(channel[2])) / (xyzMap.rows*xyzMap.cols) > 0.3)
        {
            return;
        }

        // If there is one or less visible fingers
        if (fingers_xyz.size() <= 1)
        {
            fingers_xyz.clear();
            fingers_ij.clear();

            auto indexFinger = Util::averageAroundPoint(xyzMap, cv::Point2i(index.x / 4, index.y / 4), 10);
            fingers_xyz.push_back(indexFinger);
            fingers_ij.push_back(cv::Point2i(index.x, index.y)); // SCALING
            auto angle = Util::TriangleAngleCalculation(index_left.x, index_left.y, index.x, index.y, index_right.x, index_right.y);

            if (defects_ij.size() != 0)
            {
                for (auto i = 0; i < fingers_xyz.size(); i++) 
                {
                    cv::circle(img, fingers_ij[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
                    cv::line(img, defects_ij[i], fingers_ij[i], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
                    cv::circle(img, defects_ij[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2);
                    cv::line(img, defects_ij[i], centroid_ij, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
                }
            }

            else if (angle > ANGLE_THRESHHOLD)
            {
                cv::circle(img, fingers_ij[0], 5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
                cv::line(img, fingers_ij[0], centroid_ij, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
            }

        }

        else {

            for (auto i = 0; i < fingers_xyz.size(); i++) 
            {
                cv::circle(img, fingers_ij[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
                cv::line(img, defects_ij[i], fingers_ij[i], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
                cv::circle(img, defects_ij[i], 3, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255), 2);
                cv::line(img, defects_ij[i], centroid_ij, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), 2);
            }
        }

        if (camera_name == "sr300")
        {
            cv::Mat img_dst;
            cv::resize(img, img_dst, cv::Size(640, 489), 0, 0, cv::INTER_AREA);
            cv::namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            cv::imshow("Contours", img_dst);
        }

        else
        {
            cv::namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
            cv::imshow("Contours", img);
        }

    }
```

This is what I get:
[image]

additionally, I read in [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=xymzCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=approxPolyDP%20%20convexHull&source=bl&ots=9xh9iIXIC9&sig=k4t7jktjLykKW-YsY0LOIO2WL_w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj47rDv29TUAhUOzmMKHb_ABygQ6AEIUjAH#v=onepage&q=approxPolyDP%20convexHull&f=false) this is a good idea to use the following formula for epsilon but doesn't work well at all

```
cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 0.01*cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(contours[i]), true), true);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp

Comment: it is in the code I have above `cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);`